# How to use injection class in php?

Tags: php, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a class:

```
class MongoConnection
{

    private $_m;

    private $_db;

    private $_collection;

    public function _connect($dbname, $dbcollection)
    {
    }

}
```

In another class I want to use this like as:

```
class Object
{

    private $collection;


    public function __construct(MongoConnection $mongoConnection)
    {

       $mongoConnection->_connect("", "");
    }

}
```

But it does not work for me. I get an error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Object::__construct() must be an instance of MongoConnection, none given, called in..
```

I create instance of Object class as: `$object = new Object();`

Comment: How you create the `Object` instance?

Comment: Like as: `$object = new Object();`

Comment: @John: It would be nice to see such statements in your question. Please read [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)